# Python Pandas DataFrame: untack sort the multiindex unexpectedly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to replicate the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 'a', 100, 1000],
     [1, 'b', 400, 4000],
     [2, 'c', 200, 2000],
     [3, 'd', 300, 3000],
     [1, 'b', 500, 5000]]
)
df=df.set_index([0,1,2])
df=df.unstack(level=[1,2])
print(df)
```

And here is the result:

```
    3
1   a   b   c   d   b
2   100 400 200 300 500
0                   
1   1000.0  4000.0  NaN NaN 5000.0
2   NaN NaN 2000.0  NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN 3000.0  NaN
```

my question is why (b, 500) comes last and not behind (b, 400) which would be in the expected order?

Comment: was I edit your code correctly? I caught the error `Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2`

Comment: Agree with @BearBrown, your input does not produce the output in your question.

Comment: missing one line of code to set_index, corrected it now

Answer (score 0):

just add sort_index

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 'a', 100, 1000],
     [1, 'b', 400, 4000],
     [2, 'c', 200, 2000],
     [3, 'd', 300, 3000],
     [1, 'b', 500, 5000]]
)
df=df.set_index([0,1,2])
df=df.unstack(level=[1,2]).sort_index(axis=1)
print(df)
```